# problem with send mail method

Tags: c#, email, send

In this method i send mail

```
        var mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = mailServer.EsHtml;

        mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, nomFrom,Encoding.UTF8);

        foreach(var item in mailTo)
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Key, item.Value, Encoding.UTF8));

        foreach(var item in mailCC)
            mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(item.Key, item.Value, Encoding.UTF8));

        mail.Body = message;
        mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachments));

        var clientMail = new SmtpClient();

        clientMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailFrom, passMail);

        if(mailServer.PuertoCorreo.HasValue)
            clientMail.Port = mailServer.PuertoCorreo.Value;

        clientMail.Host = mailServer.ServidorCorreo;

        clientMail.EnableSsl = mailServer.HabilitarSSL;

        clientMail.Send(mail);
```

And it works fine but in gmail in the body i got this `text਍猀搀搀昀ഀ more text` and hotmail in attach name i got this `牰敵慢瀮晤`.What is wrong in the method?

Comment: what is the expected result you should have? which text exactly are you putting the email's body?

Comment: Are you sure of the encodings you're using and are you sure you can you mix them in the same email?

Comment: I used a richtextbox control for body between text and japannese character is enter and between jap char and more text are enter and tab

Comment: One more thing in gmail the attach is fine and hotmail the body is fine

Comment: Have you tried changing your BodyEncoding to Encoding.UTF8?  It should not be Unicode as most email systems can't handle Unicode.

Comment: Well, i changed the body's encoding to UTF8 and it works fine, but now it doesn't send enter and tab to body, put on in the same text line =(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```